# ClickOnce running in downloaded context when opened in vanilla firefox (unsurprisingly)

Tags: firefox, clickonce

I want to use ClickOnce to install my application, and this works very well if I have the firefox addon installed. However, if I don't, I still want to be able to install the program.

When I click my app.application link, it downloads the file, and asks me to run it. If I do, it tells me that the deployment and application manifest are in different security zones. I'm thinking that this is because my file is downloaded.

If I install it using the addon or with IE, I instead get another error when I try to run it later with vanilla firefox. It complains that the application cannot be run from c:\DownloadDir\app.application, but from http://myserv/app.application.

Does anyone know how to solve these two problems?

Answer (score 0):

Is this an online-only application, or is it online/offline? The "different zones" issue sounds like you might have an online-only application.